# ERROR XMLConfigurationReader - Error while validating file 'cd_ambient_conf.xml' with schema 'schemas/cd_ambient_conf.xsd

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery, ambient

I configured ambient data framework in my staging website for Tridion UI 2012. But in the log file it records below error -

2

```
012-11-08 11:42:20,095 WARN  AmbientDataContext - There is no current ambient data context - the ambient data framework is not properly initialised
2012-11-08 11:42:20,204 ERROR XMLConfigurationReader - Error while validating file 'cd_ambient_conf.xml' with schema 'schemas/cd_ambient_conf.xsd'. cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'ClaimStoreProvider'. One of '{Cookies}' is expected.
```

But in documentation it is nowhere mentioned to enable cookies tag.
Question is exactly similar to second part of my previous questions-
[Error in configuring ambient data framework for Content Delivery web Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13263631/error-in-configuring-ambient-data-framework-for-content-delivery-web-service)
 (see Edit-Regarding CDA application).
Answer of this question was fit for one of my previous case. So please refer my configuration files from there. The only intention for this new question to approach a wide audience. Afterward I would be in favour to mark it as duplicate of previous one or I will cut and paste the common part in this one.
 A earlier help would be most appreciated .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have seen this error when you mix the jar files of `Tridion SP1` and `Tridion SP1#HR1`. You most likely (pretty sure) have the **cd_core.jar** from `Tridion SP1` and **not** from the `Tridion SP1 HR1`.

`Tridion SP1 HR1`  is pre-requisite for Tridion UI/XM 2012. You need to replace all the jar files from Tridion SP1 HR1 and restart the AppPool of preview site. Once you copied you will see messages like below in the log instead of the ERROR.

```
WARN  AmbientDataContext - There is no current ambient data context - the ambient data framework is not properly initialised
DEBUG AmbientDataContext - Setting current ambient data context: com.tridion.ambientdata.web.WebContext
INFO  AmbientDataConfig - Found claimStoreProvider definition in configuration file: com.tridion.siteedit.preview.PreviewClaimStoreProvider.
```

Comment: Thanks Ram G ,very impressive  answer. But how i will get rid of the warn " AmbientDataContext - There is no current ambient data context - the ambient " . As due to this i am getting continue alert "Preview for this page is not up to date". even after going with yes for update  preview nothing happens. Could you please help me in this regard. This question is closed so  i am going to put my issue in a separate question.